# Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NSContiguousString' to 'NSNumber

Tags: swift, casting, firebase, nsstring, nsnumber

```
if let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as? String{

            currentUser = User(name: snapshot.value["name"] as! String ,phoneNumber: snapshot.value["phoneNumber"] as! String, userId: userID ,  isOnline: snapshot.value["isOnline"] as! Bool, key: "", lastName: snapshot.value["lastName"] as! String, photoUrl: "")

        }
```

Im using Firebase as MBaas and Im getting this error at the currentUser line, curiously this isn't happening all the time,but only sometimes when I am leaving the app (home button) or reentering its occurs..
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8):

try this (swift 3)

```
(userID as AnyObject).integerValue
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to convert a string into number that's why this happens